# How get values/data from object

Tags: flutter, object, get

I'm trying to get values from an object which I have filled before.

Code - this is my Object class:

```
class ProductObject extends Object{
  String _entries;

  ProductObject(
    this._entries,
  );
}
```

Now I'm trying to fill the object in my code.
Code - here I fill the object:

```
return GestureDetector(
   onTap: () { 
     ProductObject productObject = ProductObject(
        'Any Data',
     );

print('newProductObejct: ' + productObject._image.toString());
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductDetail(productObject)));
},
```

The code 'productObject._entries.toString()' is working.
I can get the data from object.

But if i would passe the object to a other display
i can't get the object data.
Code - this is my seconde page:

```
class ProductDetail  extends StatefulWidget {
  var _product_data;
  ProductDetail(this._product_data,{Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductDetail createState() => _ProductDetail (_product_data);
}



class _ProductDetail extends State<ProductDetail > {
  var _product_data;
  _ProductDetail(this._product_data);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      
      body:
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            print('newProductObejct: ' + _product_data._image.toString());
          },child: Text('text'),),                   
    );
  }
}
```

On the second page i got a error.
Like this:

- The following _TypeError was thrown while dispatching a pointer event:

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'function result'

How can I pass the object data to another page and call them there?

Comment: Include the code causing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the constructor in `_ProductDetail` state class. You can simply access member `_product_data` from the state class like this:

```
widget._product_data
```

Comment: Hello @Peter,
thx for you answer.
After i try your example i got the the messgae 'Instance of 'ProductObject'.
How i can get the data from the Instance.

Comment: Like `widget._product_data._entries`.